# Idiomatic way to call a BAPI within CDS-generated BOPF Business Object (ABAP Programming Model for SAP Fiori)

Tags: abap, cds

What is the idiomatic way of calling a BAPI from within a generated BOPF Business Object? In this case I mean the ones generated using the `@ObjectModel.*` CDS annotations.

For example I would like to call a BAPI when a Business Object is saved. Right now I would use a Determination. The downside is I still have to create database tables in order use CUD-operations and an entry is written into those tables, even though I would like to use the BAPI to save the data.

Any ideas?